# Why is the output different with React setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### I don't know why

- When I use `this.setState({count: count+1}`
  Clicking multiple times will only update count once
- When I use `this.setState({count: this.setState.count})`
  Each click updates the count
- Why different?

```
       class Demo extends React.Component {
            state = {count: 0};
            render() {
                const {count} = this.state;
                return  <button onClick={() => this.setState({count: count+1})}>count</button>
            }
            shouldComponentUpdate(){
                return false;
            } 

        }
```

- Environment `react@16.8.4`

Comment: The first one is working as it should. The second one is probably causing some sort of weird side effect bypassing normal lifecycles.

Comment: 1. You explicitly tell React not to update in shouldComponentUpdate. 2. ˋthis.setState.countˋ should be undefined.

Comment: I believe that you wanted to have the `this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });` in your second example instead of the `this.setState.count + 1`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because their scopes are different.

`this.setState({count: this.setState.count+1})`actions of loading `state.count` number and reassignment  are in same onClick event scope.

But `count` variable in `this.setState({count: count+1})`  is defined in upper `render()` scope and onClick event only receive `count` as upper level variable. Therefore, render() function is only run once, so `count` in `render()` only initialized once(loading `state.count` only once); when you click button, only onClick event scope will be executed(reassignment actions will be executed multiple times), rather than `render()` scope. That is why `count` variable in onClick event will be always 0.

There is a simple equivalent example to your case:

```js
state={count:0}

function upperLevel() {
  
  
  let {count} = state;

  function downlevel() {
    state = {
      count: count + 1
    }
    console.log(state);
  }

  downlevel();
  downlevel();
  downlevel();


}

upperLevel()
```

If we move `let {count} = state;` into `downlevel()` then the number will be increased.

```js
state = {count: 0}

function upperLevel() {
  //let {count} = state;
  function downlevel() {
    let {count} = state;
    state = {count: count + 1 }
    console.log(state);
  }

  downlevel();
  downlevel();
  downlevel();
}

upperLevel()
```

Comment: I also thought scopes, but I didn't figure out what was going on. Now  I'm clear, thank u!